# What Keras models would be best for output of lists of word vectors?

Tags: keras, word-embeddings, word2vec

Imagine a regression model that is to be trained on data consisting of questions and answers expressed in text.

The questions and answers are converted to lists of word vectors using some good word vector model, with filtering and padding of vectors for consistency. Now, the idea is to train the model such that it accepts as input the questions, which are lists of word vectors, and the targets for training are the answers, which are lists of word vectors.

What models might be suited to such a task (however feeble they might be, given the pretty high dimensionality of the problem)?

Note that this is explicitly not a task involving training a model to select an appropriate answer from a bank of existing answers; the goal is to generate an answer using solely the model.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=question+answer+model+neural+network&oq=question+answer+model+neural+network&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l3.8496j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Sycorax I'm talking about generating an output of word vectors, not selecting from an existing set of answers. They are very different topics, with the former vastly more difficult.

Comment: You should edit your post to clarify because right now it reads as an ambiguous description of a standard question/answer task.

Comment: @Sycorax Added a sentence at the end. :+1: